# rails error compiling css asset

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I'm using compass, try to import my custom scss file in application.scss and have this error:
[image]

here my application.scss code:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree
 */

@import "foundation_and_overrides";
@import "pnp";
```

if I remove require_tree error message will disappear but my scss file (pnp.scss) will not be loaded to the page

Comment: Where is the `button` mixin located? It seems your `pnp` file is trying to use it, but it cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file called `custom.css.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets` and then use all the imports there

```
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
@import "pnp";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem may be that require_self is occurring before require_tree. Meaning that `pnp` styles won't have access to any other style sheets that may be loaded after it (ie, that contain a mix in).

To avoid this kind of confusion, I usually keep all imports in one SCSS file and just require that in application.css.

```
# application.css

/*
 *= require normalize
 *= require base
*/


# base.scss

@import "foundation_and_overrides";
@import "constants";
@import "buttons";
@import "pnp";
```